# Where is defined the according type for the JSON output in Zend Framework 2?

Tags: json, zend-framework2, http-accept-encoding

I activated the `JsonStrategy` in a ZF2 application and can get JSON output now using [AcceptableViewModelSelector Controller Plugin](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/modules/zend.mvc.plugins.html#acceptableviewmodelselector-plugin).

It works only with the HTTP Request parameter `Accept` containing `application/json`.

Where is `application/json` defined as proper value for JSON output? (How) Can I define and use `foo/bar` instead?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look here:

```
Zend\View\Strategy\JsonStrategy;
```

You can implement your own custom strategy in the same manner no problem. Much cleaner than hard coding into the controller as it can be reused.

Comment: You mean using strategies _instead_ of the `AcceptableViewModelSelector`? I thought, I have to use a _combination_ of the `AcceptableViewModelSelector` and the strategies? The approach is: (0. Implement the strategy, if a custom one needed.) 1. Register the strategies; 2. Detect the Accept value with the AcceptableViewModelSelector; 3. (In the Controller action / REST method) return a `ViewModel` object, supported by one of the registered strategies; 4. The `Zend\View\View` will process the `ViewModel` object according to the chosen strategy (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/17350883/2019043).

Answer (score 0):

Directly in the definition array of the accept criteria:

```
class SomeController extends AbstractActionController
{
   protected $acceptCriteria = array(
      'Zend\View\Model\JsonModel' => array(
         'application/json', // <-- here
      ),
      'Zend\View\Model\FeedModel' => array(
         'application/rss+xml',
      ),
   );

   public function apiAction()
   {
      $viewModel = $this->acceptableViewModelSelector($this->acceptCriteria);

      // Potentially vary execution based on model returned
      if ($viewModel instanceof JsonModel) {
         // ...
      }
   }
}
```